# Can tensor-cubes ever come in handy for solving algebraic or differential equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

We've seen equations of the form $Ax = a$ for two vectors $x$ and $a$ which we can solve by matrix multiplication.

Is there ever an instance where we'd solve an equation where $A$ is a $n$ x $n$ x $n$ tensor instead of an $n$ x $n$ matrix? What sort of system of equations would that correspond to?